# show current date and time when log print in lof file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

could you please tell me how to add a timestamp in logs when it print/writes in file? it means `it shows current data and time` when log is printed in file.

I  tried like this, but not showing the correct output .
I added this

```
const consoleLogger = new winston.transports.Console({
  timestamp: function() {
    const today = moment();
    return today.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  },
  format: winston.format.json(),
  colorize: true,
  level: "debug"
});
```

**still not working**

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-kapitsa-j1sku

**Current output without timestamp**

```
{"message":"running → PORT (src/index.js:10)","level":"info"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most options like `timestamp` and `json` became [formatters](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1350) in `winston@3`. You have to combine 2 formaters into one.

`consoleLogger` will become to:

```
const consoleLogger = new winston.transports.Console({
  timestamp: true,
  colorize: true,
  level: "debug",
  format: winston.format.combine(
    // the order is important
    winston.format.timestamp({
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    }),
    winston.format.json()
  )
});
```

and `logger`:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [consoleLogger]
});
```

My complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-knuth-yon2u

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below solution works for you.

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, printf} = format;

const transport = new transports.Console({
  exitOnError: false,
  format: combine(
    ...(environment === 'dev' ? [format.colorize()] : []),
    timestamp(),
    printf(info => `${info.timestamp} [${info.level}]: ${info.message}`)
  ),
  colorize: true,
  level: 'debug',
});

const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(timestamp(), appendTimestamp({ tz: 'Add your timezone'}), myFormat),
  transports: [transport],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: 'FILE_NAME.log'
    }),
  ],
});
```